# Use Common Proto NuGet in C#

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, protocol-buffers

I am trying to use a Common proto project which contains common messages used.

My project structure for the common is this. It is a .Net 5 Class library.

[image]

I publish it as NuGet with following to include the files:

[image]

I then try to use the NuGet in another project with same structure. Here I already added the NuGet and I can see common.proto inside:

[image]

I then add the following in the .csproj:

[image]

And finally, try to use it:

[image]

But I receive errors when I try to compile:

[image]

It seems I followed exactly same way as here: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-dotnet/issues/183

But it doesn't work. Maybe I am doing something wrong?

I also tried `import "Protos/common.proto` but it did not work.